# Photo Organizer Server

Tags: php, image, photos, file-organization

Does anybody know of a server side project that can be used to organize photos?

I have tons of images and I want to have them on a server. The functionality that I'm looking is very simple:

- be able to browse large sets of images (something like google images)
- The software needs to be generate the thumbnails.
- Download the full resolution image.
- Some kind of security would be nice!
- A PHP based software would be ideal.

Tks.